# Bulk insertion using laravel eloquent create method

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

I need to insert a large amount of data in a database. I can use the `ModelName::insert()` method to insert the data in chunks. The problem is that I cannot use the `insert` method here because a third-party package performs some action while creating a record.

Can you please guide me on how I can use the Laravel Eloquent create method to insert large data in chunks?

Comment: o your insert method is been overwritten by an extection/trait by a third party library?

Answer (score 0):

**[Chunking Results](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#chunking-results)**

If you need to process thousands of Eloquent records, use the chunk command. The chunk method will retrieve a "chunk" of Eloquent models, feeding them to a given Closure for processing. Using the chunk method will conserve memory when working with large result sets:

```php
ModelName::chunk(200, function ($models) {
    foreach ($models as $model) {
        //
    }
});
```

Comment: This method will run 200 queries for each insertion and I want something like insert method which I think run a single query foreach chunk. Moreover this method is used to retrieve and update data from database not to create new models.